# How to Convert dataTable to list without specifying Table Column names

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datatable, lambda

I am fetching data from Oracle Database using oracleClient. It returns the result as DataTable.
When converting the dataTable to list, It needs to specify the table column name

```
    List<ReportView> result = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new ReportView
                {
                   AvailableBalance = r.Field<decimal>("BALANCE_AMT"),
                   OrderDate = r.Field<DateTime>("ORDER_DATE"),
                   OrderListType = r.Field<string>("TYPE_CODE"),
                   OrderNumber = r.Field<string>("ORDER_NUM"),
                   OrderTotal = r.Field<decimal>("ORDER_TOTAL_AMT")
                 }).ToList();
              }
```

and the model is something like

```
    public class ReportView
    {
      public decimal AvailableBalance { get; set; }
      public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
      public string OrderListType { get; set; }
      public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
      public decimal OrderTotal { get; set; }
    }
```

Is there any other way to fetch data without specifying the column name every time.

Comment: No, there isn't. If it's important for you could provide  a `static ReportView GetView(DataRow row)` method in `ReportView`. But this method still needs to presume the column names.

Comment: May be this article will usefull for you http://sharpdevpt.blogspot.ru/2010/05/convert-datatable-into-poco-using.html

Comment: In fact, there is a number of ways to do it, starting from any of the numerous ORMs, from [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) to [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), and ending with simple Reflection-based code.